# Buffer I/O error on device sda2, logical block 66326416

Tags: linux, initrd

I have a linux image customized based on Centos 5.8
This linux-image was installing well till recently. Of late, the installation is failing with the error:
"Buffer I/O error on device sda2, logical block 66326416" and series of such messages displayed on screen, causing the installation to fail. Found this failure is observed for a new set of seagate HDDs. On the same server with new Seagate HDD, RHEL5 is installed successfully (ruling out HDD hardware error).

I tried to load all the drivers that are there in RHEL5, but that was failing too.

Am looking for pointers to narrow down the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Sri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i got it after much struggle. The issue is resolved by replacing the isci driver with megasr (my raid controller driver) in initrd (that is used while installation). When isci.ko driver detected my Seagate HDD, it was getting errors during installation. After replacing isci.ko with megasr driver, the installation went fine.